# Font baseline broken on Chrome and Firefox on Windows

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, firefox, font-face

I have a weird issue on which I've lost hours to no avail. We have a website with a custom font implemented as:

```
@font-face{
font-family:LilGroteskBold;
src:url(../fonts/LilGroteskBold.eot);
src:url(../fonts/LilGroteskBold.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
url(../fonts/LilGroteskBold.woff) format("woff"),
url(../fonts/LilGroteskBold.ttf) format("truetype"),
url(../fonts/LilGroteskBold.svg#LilGroteskBold) format("svg")
}
```

Now everything works smoothly on OSX, and on IE (yes, that's not something you hear often) but the font baseline is completely broken on Chrome and Firefox on Windows. An image of the problem is here:

http://www.restons-serieux.com/broken_baseline.jpg

As you can see, u, a, e are lower than the baseline, m and r are higher... it's a mess.

We suspected that one of the file types was causing problems, but we tried only woff, only svg, without svg, etc, to no avail: it always behaves this way.

Has anyone else experienced this? Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change font-weight property to bold instead of a number, that should probably do the trick :)